# Import Jira to Azure Devops. visualization of Jira Board Kanban to Azure Board

Tags: azure, import, jira

We are experiencing a huge problem. After a sucessful operation of exporting Jira tasks, bugs, and so on using Solidify Tool into AZURE DEVOPS when we try to check SPRINTS and BOARDS they do not show. We also do not know how to link (if there is any possible way) them. If anyone fixed this before, can please give us a help? Tks.

It is not showing on Board neither on Sprints what we have just imported. However they are listed on work items.

Comment: Does maybe [this](https://github.com/solidify/jira-azuredevops-migrator/issues/310) help?